# Eror using npx react-native init AwesomeProjectError in linux

Tags: react-native

[image: error image]

When trying to create a new app project in react-native `npx react-native init AwesomeProject` Error it pops up `npx: instaló 642 en 107.54s Unexpected token =` and doesn't create the project